# Making Story Map with two photos that can swipe?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map, swipe

I am trying to make a story map with some heritage data. I want to have a picture of each heritage site two times(Swipable: that i can swipe between the two photos), one photo for the current and one for earlier years. It can be a swipe or any other tool that is available as long as it is not the same heritage sites for two points.

I am open to suggestions on the platform but i am familiar with ArcGIS Online.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for swipable photos within an HTML Popup.  Can you edit your to make whether that is what you are after clearer, please?  The alternative is swipable basemaps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Yes that is right. I want swipable photos not swipable base maps.

Comment: I'm afraid that there isn't anything prebuilt for this; You will have to use custom code for this, and it's quite doable with some JavaScript & CSS. See this page for an example: http://www.nbcnews.com/id/49646622/ns/weather/t/after-views-jersey-shore-towns-damaged-superstorm-sandy/

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I think you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many JQuery Plugins as well as custom Javascript which can do this. A quick Google search gives me (I haven't personally used any of them, so take this list with a pinch of salt) :

- [jQuery Before and After Image Comparison Plugin - Image Reveal](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Before-After-Image-Comparison-Plugin-Image-Reveal.html)
- [A “Before And After” Image Comparison Slide Control in HTML5](http://thenewcode.com/819/A-Before-And-After-Image-Comparison-Slide-Control-in-HTML5)

The code is relatively straightforward, and you could easily set this up with some basic JavaScript & CSS.

Additionally, here is an example, of what I guess is similar to what you want to achieve:

http://www.nbcnews.com/id/49646622/ns/weather/t/after-views-jersey-shore-towns-damaged-superstorm-sandy/